# Get Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog' when installing Browserfy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, terminal, osx-mavericks

When I type:

```
 npm install -g browserify
```

My terminal spits this out:

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:75:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
```

I'm new to node. I have Node v0.12.0, Ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0], Rails 4.1.8. I'm using the terminal on a Mac. I have OS X 10.9.5, Mavericks.

I've been trying some solutions I've found online but nothing has worked. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, looks like I have the exact same issue. Can you run the 'npm' command? It throws the error as well... did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I cannot & I have not found a solution yet.